# How i can create a csv file from a sql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, csv

I have a `SQL` file that have some query in it i want to create a `CSV` file from this query. Current `SQL` file included the following code:

```
SELECT
    ID AS 'Donor ID',
    directorsComments AS 'Director Comments',
    external_donor_id AS 'Donor Number',
    CASE
        WHEN is_approved = '1'
            THEN 'Approved'
        ELSE 'Not Approved'
    END AS 'Approval Status',

    donor_status AS 'Donor Status',
    screening_status AS 'Screening Status',
    Title AS 'Title',
    firstName AS 'First Name',
    lastName AS 'Last Name',

    dateStarted AS 'Created At',
    dateSubmitted AS 'Last Updated',
    ipAddress AS 'IP',
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done directly without PHP using the SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' command : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: maybe also `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` ( is this the default ? )

Comment: @amdixon: yes, I forgot that - first day back after Christmas - could also add the ENCLOSED BY '"' option as well

Comment: so all i need to add these parameters with my SELECT query?
I was trying like this..
        $list = array
        (
         "Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
         "Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
              );

              $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

            foreach ($list as $line)
            {
          fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
         }

Comment: That's correct, there is an example in the link I gave you